# how to find how many number of jobs are working in my oracle database

Tags: oracle

I have created some jobs using dbms_scheduler.create_job with the job name 'ABC' and run the job using dbms_scheduler.run_job now i just want to know the status of that job whether its running or not so please give the query to check the status of the job.

Answer (score 2):

Use `dba_scheduler_job_run_details` view to get the details,

```
SELECT log_date,
       job_name,
       status,
       req_start_date,
       actual_start_date,
       run_duration
FROM   dba_scheduler_job_run_details
WHERE  job_name = 'ABC'
ORDER BY log_date desc;
```